# I cannot update text with tview

Tags: go, tui

I'm using [tview](https://github.com/rivo/tview) in the Go language.

I want to use the following code to display "hoge" on the terminal, but it does not show up.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/rivo/tview"
)

func main() {
    tui := newTui()
    tui.Run()
    tui.WriteMessage("hoge")
}

type Tui struct {
    app  *tview.Application
    text *tview.TextView
}

func (t *Tui) Run() {
    t.app.Run()
}

func (t *Tui) WriteMessage(message string) {
    fmt.Fprintln(t.text, message)
}

func newTui() *Tui {
    text := tview.NewTextView()

    app := tview.NewApplication()
    app.SetRoot(text, true)

    text.SetChangedFunc(func() { app.Draw() })

    tui := &Tui{app: app, text: text}

    return tui
}
```

I don't want to update the text in the `newTui()` function.

How do I get it to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`func (*Application) Run()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/rivo/tview#Application.Run):

> `Run` starts the application and thus the event loop. This function
> returns when `Stop()` was called.

i.e. The statement `tui.WriteMessage("hoge")` in your program is never reached because `Run()` doesn't return until stopped explicitly. So to see `hoge` printed in the terminal, you must call `tui.WriteMessage("hoge")` *before* `Run()`.

```golang
func main() {
    tui := newTui()
    tui.WriteMessage("hoge")
    tui.Run()
}
```

Comment: Oh! So I can use a goroutine to call `tui.WriteMessage()` before calling `tui.Run()` to write text at random times, right?

Comment: @tekunikaruza I assume that that should be possible, but I haven't tried it myself so I can't say for sure.